# Is there any method to capture the entire user input in dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot

I'm building a telegram chatbot with google dialogflow. I need to save all conversations in a database (Yes, I know that Dialogflow has the history built-in, but I need to store in a database). So, I'm trying to save the history to firebase firestore with the intent function, called every time that my intent is matched (functions are defined in the inline editor, cloud functions). So, I need the user id and the full message typed by the user and the bot (not only parameters). Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I would send the conversation to logs and capture these using [`Audit Logs`](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/audit-logging) to capture them into Cloud Logging. Then I would [link Cloud Logging to Firebase](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9748636?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article). You can see here how to [see and write Logs into Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/writing-and-viewing-logs).